# what the limit of $\lim_{x→0}f(\sqrt{4 +x^2})$

Tags: limits

I want to use the following graph to explain one-sided limits and their relationship to two sided limits.

But I am not sure how should I make it organised and clear.

Let's say determining the limit:  $$\lim_{x→0} f(\sqrt{4 +x^2})$$

The graph of function $f$ on the intervals [-5,5] is shown below.
[image]

Comment: What do you think is the value of the limit?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

After the graph, we have

$$\lim_{t\to 2^+}f(t)=-3$$

on the other hand

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{4+x^2}=2^+$$

**Proof**

Given $ \epsilon>0 $.

$$\lim_{t\to 2^+}f(t)=-3\implies$$
$$\exists \eta>0\;:\;\forall t\in\color{red}{(2,2+\eta)}\; $$
$$|f(t)+3|<\epsilon$$

**and**

$$\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{4+x^2}=2\implies$$
$$\exists \delta>0\;:\;\forall x\in(-\delta,\delta) $$
$$\sqrt{4+x^2}\in\color{red}{(2,2+\eta)}$$

The combination gives

$$\forall x\in(-\delta,\delta)\;\; |f(\sqrt{4+x^2})+3|<\epsilon$$

we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(\sqrt{4+x^2})=-3$$